Suppose $ -1 \le a+b \le 1 , \ 1 \le a+2b \le 3$ , find the range of $a+3b$.
Suppose $a,b \in \Bbb{R}$, $\begin{cases}
-1 \le a+b \le 1  & (1) \\
1 \le a+2b \le 3 & (2)
\end{cases}$, find the range of $a+3b$.
Solution 1：
Since  $\begin{cases}
-1 \le-a-b \le 1  & (3) \\
1 \le a+2b \le 3 & (2)
\end{cases}$, by $(3)+(2)$, we have $0 \le b \le 4 \quad (4)$.
By $(2)+(4)$,  $a+3b=(a+2b)+b \in [1,7]$
Solution 2：
By$(1)+2 \times (4)$ , $a+3b=(a+b)+2b \in [-1,9]$
Solution 3：
Since  $-(a+b) \in[-1,1]$, $2(a+2b) \in [2,6]$, we have $a+3b=-(a+b)+2(a+2b) \in [1,7]$.
Why the solution 2 have a different answer ?

When you're adding various multiples of inequality ranges, note the result represents the maximum potential range of the resulting expression, not necessarily what the valid range actually is. The lower bound of the range will only hold if the values of the variables corresponding to each of the $2$ lower bounds being added can exist simultaneously, and similarly for the upper bound. However, that doesn't necessarily always occur.
For example, with your solution $2$, the lower bound of $-1$ occurs only when $b = 0$ and, in inequality $(1)$ which was added in, $-1 = a + b \;\to\; a = -1$. However, then $a + 2b = -1$, which doesn't satisfy inequality $(2)$ requiring $1 \le a + 2b$. Also, the upper bound of $9$ requires that $b = 4$ and $a + b = 1 \;\to\; a = -3$, but then $a + 2b = 5 \not\le 3$ in $(2)$.
As obtained in your solutions $1$ and $3$, to show $[1, 7]$ is the actual range, instead of it being a subset of this, from $(2)$ and $(4)$ being added, the lower bounds have $(a, b) = (1, 0)$ and the upper bounds have  $(a, b) = (-5, 4)$, with both sets of $(a, b)$ values satisfying the original $(1)$ and $(2)$ inequalities. Due to the simple nature of the inequalities, i.e., constant bounds and linear function expressions, this implies continuity between the bounds, i.e., all values in $[1,7]$ are valid.
However, more complicated cases may result in only certain disjoint subsets of $[1, 7]$ being valid. In those situations, we may need to use something having $a$ and $b$ being functions of a parameter.
To show how that's done in your case, and to be more robust, note that $b$ goes from $0$ to $4$ (which matches your $(4)$'s range), so we can then use it directly with a parameter $b_0$, i.e., $b = b_0$. Then to have $a$ go from $1$ down to $-5$ linearly for $b_0$ from $0$ to $4$, we can use $a = j + kb_0$ for some constants $j$ and $k$. At $b_0 = 0$, this gives $j = 1$. At $b_0 = 4$, to have $a = -5$ means $-5 = 1 + 4k \;\to\; -6 = 4k \;\to\; k = -\frac{3}{2}$. We then get
$$b = b_0, \;\; a = 1 - \frac{3b_0}{2}, \;\; 0 \le b_0 \le 4$$
Using this gives
$$a + b = 1 - \frac{b_0}{2} \;\;\to\;\; a + b \le 1 \land (a + b \ge 1 - \frac{4}{2} = -1)$$
so inequality $(1)$ holds. Also,
$$a + 2b = 1 + \frac{b_0}{2} \;\;\to\;\; a + 2b \ge 1 \land (a + 2b \le 1 + \frac{4}{2} = 3)$$
which shows that $(2)$ holds. Finally, we have
$$a + 3b = 1 + \frac{3b_0}{2}$$
This is a continuous, strictly increasing linear function in $b_0$, with a minimum of $1$ at $b_0 = 0$ and a maximum of $7$ at $b_0 = 4$, so its range is all values in $[1,7]$.

Thanks for your explanation, but I wonder how could you come up with the equation: $a=1-\cfrac{3b_0}{2}$ ?

@Winston You're welcome. I've just added an explanation to my answer of how I came up with the parametric equations, including that of $a=1-\frac{3b_0}{2}$. Please let me know if you would like more detail about that, or anything else in my answer.

The equality obtained in 2 actually cannot hold. Take the upper bound as an example. If the the upper bound in 2 holds, then both (1) and (4) hold their upper bound. However, note that (4)=(3)+(2)=(3)-(1). If the upper bound of (4) holds, then the lower bound of (1) must hold, which is impossible when the upper bound of (1) has already held.

The conclusion of solution 2 isn't a false statement.  Saying $a + 3b \in [-1, 9]$ is correct, but it is incomplete.  It isn't a statement of range.  Range means finding the smallest possible upper bound, not just any upper bound.  Similarly for lower bounds.
To solve the problem, first you have space1 which is everything in between the lines
$$a+b = -1$$
$$a+b = 1$$
Then you have space2 which is everything between the lines
$$a+2b = 1$$
$$a+2b=3$$
The intersection of those 2 spaces forms a diamond.  So you want to look at the set of lines
$$a + 3b = z$$
and ask what is the largest and smallest $z$ for which the line $a+3b=z$ passes through the diamond.  And if you draw it, you'll see it occurs at the top left and bottom right of the diamond.  Here is an linked desmos graph of the excluded spaces to show you:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/g0l4pw6yj1
The bottom right diamond corner is the intersection of $a+b=1$ and $a+2b=1$, which is $(a,b) = (1,0)$.  So $a+3b=z=1$ is the smallest possible $z$.
The top left diamond corner is the intersection of $a+b = -1$ and $a+2b=3$, which is $(a,b)=(-5, 4)$ which implies $a+3b=z=7$ is the largest possible $z$.

In inequality deducing question, what we usually do is based on the assumption we can ''derive'' something, so for example, $$0\le x\le2\color{red}{\implies}1\le x+1\le3\color{red}{\implies}1\le x+1\le4$$ This shows the range of $x+1$ is a subset of $[1,4]$, but it does not show it is $[1,4]$ (you know the actual range is $[1,3]$.
In your answer, it is also the same. You derive $b\in[0,4]$  and $a+b\in[-1,1]$, so it means $a+3b\in[-1,9]$. However, this only shows the range of $a+3b$ is a subset of $[-1,9]$, you need extra argument to claim the range is $[-1,9]$ (and of course this is not correct because the maximum of two ranges cannot hold concurrently).
Actually all your three solutions are not rigourous enough, I suggest you can take a look at John's answer.

I think the method in the solution 3 will always work, since it constructs the direct relationship between $a+3b$ and  $a+b, a+2b$, is this true ?

Hmm yes, originally I mean you should check that $a+b=1$ and $a+2b=3$ can hold concurrently. But seems this is obvious in linear functions. Ypu are right, sol 3 is good enough.
